# Multiple applications accessing the same data

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

So my team is developing an API in PHP . 
My main concern is what happen 2 people call to update the same row.

So if one API call will do a read then process info then write, what happens if another API call does the same thing for the same row of data. We are using Postgres OR Mysql.

```
User has 100 dollars.
API Call 1 to ADD 20 1 reads 100.
API Call 2 to Subtract 20 reads 100.
API Call 1 writes 120;
API Call 2 write 80;( instead of 100);
```

I know there is a solution involving locking tables or rows, will that solve my problem?

I need a solution where API call 2 doesn't fail, but rather waits or retries.

[EDIT]

I should go in further detail of what we are doing. It's a browser mmo game that where it has 2 parts. A PHP REST API and Java server.

The browser makes AJAX GET API calls ex. : Build Factory for $40k
PHP API Check if enough funds, and return JSON. SO -$40k from player.

Our Server ticks have concurrent database calls using boneCP to Update Values like Funds.

So from my previous example CALL 1 would be our PHP API and CALL 2 would be the server ticks.

Comment: Reconsider the ACID properties and make sure they being preserved. After that check SS2PL

Comment: With Postgres using the serializable isolation level would prevent you from writing the wrong value (you'll have to deal with the errors though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn about [transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html), [transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), and [explicit row-level locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html):

```
select ... for update
```

In your case, also look into using expressions. Your life would be much simpler if you issued someting like:

```
update account set amount = amount - 20 where id = ?
```

Comment: I have used Transactions in MySQL InnoDB engine, but how does a transaction stop this. The API calls are separate, they are not done with the same call.  (Also your amount = amount - input is something simple and easy and I can't believe I overlooked that. (also i just saw you updated)

Comment: If you've a transaction and a select for update, call 2 can't read the row until call 1 is done. Similarly, if the two concurrent transactions are serializable. (You've a lot of reading to do. Don't skip that step.)

Comment: I got that the 2nd call can't read because of a row lock, but does that mean it fails or waits for unlock?

Comment: @CrisG: normally, it waits until the locks are released when the transaction ends (successfully or not). Occasionally, it can deadlock and fail too.

Comment: You should also be thinking about avoiding read-modify-write cycles, and where that's unavoidable about optimistic concurrency control.

Comment: How do you avoid read-mod-write? By using a query like amount = amount - 20? But what if the algorithms get more complex then just -20 or +20 ? And what if they involve query other tables for info to determine what data to write.

Comment: @CrisG: Yes and, per Craig's answer, sometimes it's unavoidable, though you can often leverage triggers in more complicated cases. And per an earlier comment, you've a lot of reading to do; don't skip that step unless you plan on hiring someone. There is no easy to use magic bullet or recipe when it comes to this kind of consideration — especially if your transactions are manipulating money.

Comment: @CrisG A single API call may do multiple *queries*, but within a single consistent *transaction*.

Answer (score 2):

Your API is badly designed and needs to be fixed. Instead of:

1. User has 100 dollars.
2. API Call 1 to ADD 20 1 reads 100.
3. API Call 2 to Subtract 20 reads 100.
4. API Call 1 writes 120;
5. API Call 2 write 80;( instead of 100);

You should instead have a flow like:

1. User has 100 dollars
2. API call 1 to "Add 20 to account 1", so account 1 changes from 100 to 120 and returns the new value 120
3. API call 2 to "Subtract 20 from account 1", so account 1 changes from 120 to 100 and returns the new value 100

Similarly, if you're transferring between two accounts you would *always* use an API call that does a *transfer* rather than doing an add, then a separate subtract or vice versa.

In other words, you need to redesign your API so that your database state is consistent at the start of, and end of, every API call. To ensure that an API call that uses multiple SQL statements is consistent even if aborted half way through you must [wrap the API call's work up in a *transaction*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) and if you're not going to use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, do appropriate `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` commands if you'll be doing a read-modify-write within the transaction.

You need to avoid [*read-modify-write* cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-modify-write) by client applications.

In situations where a read-modify-write is unavoidable, so two or more API calls must be kept consistent, you should use [*optimistic concurrency control*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) to protect against update collisions. In that case your scenario would play out as follows:

1. User has 100 dollars.
2. API Call 1 reads account 1, gets value 100 and rowversion 1
3. API Call 2 reads account 1, gets value 100 and rowversion 1
4. API Call 1 adds 20 to fetched value 100, sends new value 120 and rowversion 1. Succeeds because sent rowversion is equal to in-database rowversion.
5. API Call 2 subtracts 20 from fetched value 100, sends new value 80 and new rowversion 1. *fails* with an error return because database rowversion is newer than sent rowversion, so somebody else has modified the row since we fetched it. The second API caller must fetch the row again and re-try.

Comment: Well what we have is the PHP API script that Listens to AJAX calls and reads and writes to the database. And we also have a java server that constantly reads and updates the database based on our algorithm. 

This is essentially a browser mmo game, where for AJAX GET API call could be "build a building for $40k" then update the database for player. 
But while all this is happening the Java server handles server ticks for constant player income for the player X ammount every 5 seconds.
Income is only 1 example. ( I wanted to give you the idea whats going on in case there is a better way)

Comment: @CrisG Well, for one thing, if income is constant you can store time since last transaction + income rate, that way you aren't updating the DB every 5s for every player just to update something you can calculate trivially on the fly.

Comment: Yes, we did figure that out with the use of time stamps.